# “Realm.framework” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified. Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

I updated the realm that I used in my app to the latest version (10.5.0), and this warning keep prompting whenever I run the app on Xcode:
"“Realm.framework” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified."

How can I prevent this warning from prompting? Will my user see this error when he/she uses my app?

Comment: Go to XCode->Preferences->Accounts and  re-authenticate with your developer AppleID. You may also need to log into developer.apple.com and agree to the latest terms and conditions.